No cerificate is in /etc/ssl/certs
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.18.18) for an SOC platform.
The system has openssl compiled, and there is an application connecting to cloud server.  But the application failed to ran with error of 'Error: SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/ssl/certs/aptest.crt' does not exist or is empty.
I checked the /etc/ssl/certs/, it is empty!
So, where is the aptest.crt generated from (or by whom) and how to install it to /etc/ssl/certs/

aptest.crt is not a file usually existing on systems, i.e. it must be something specific to the application you are running. So check with whereever this application comes from.

I am not familiar with SSL or CA, so in PC-Linux (Ubuntu for example), where are files in  /etc/ssl/certs/ from ? In my case, application is a client to connect to cloud server, so what CA should come from (server or the local application package) to make the connection succeed?

"where are files in /etc/ssl/certs/ from" - some files come from the distribution, some from application specific setups. The file in question is not a file from the system, i.e. it is instead something special your application expects. So you need to check with this specific (unknown) application.

Got you more than before. :-). I want to confirm that the CA is from the specific client application, NOT from the cloud server?

Since the file seems to be missing (hence the error) and there is nothing known about the use of this file in the unknown application, it is impossible to confirm anything about this file.
